# change factor values in a row by factor values of another row

Tags: r, dataframe

here is an example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(v1=factor(c("empty","a","empty","c","b")),
                 v2=factor(c("empty","z","z","y","x")))
```

I now want to replace values of `empty` in `v1` if there is a non-empty
analog in `v2`. 
In this example `z` in `v2` maps to `a` in `v1` in the second row.
So the `empty` in the third row should also be `a`.

The final data frame should therefore be:

```
df.final <- data.frame(v1=factor(c("empty","a","a","c","b")),
                       v2=factor(c("empty","z","z","y","x")))
```

what is a solution to change this?
I tried it with two nested for loops but that takes forever (~15 minutes for my data frame with 25000 rows and several thousand factor levels).

For various reasons I want to keep the factor levels and don't want to change to numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (I'm assuming you have one unique value in `v1` per each value in `v2`- correct me if I'm wrong). Here I'm trying to reduce the problem by operating only on `v2` values which aren't `empty` using a *negative binary join* while *assigning by reference* using the `:=` operator

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), v2)
df[!J("empty"), v1 := v1[v1 != "empty"][1L], by = v2]
```

---

**Edit**

A more consistent with a real data set option will probably be

```
df[!J("empty"), v1 := replace(v1, v1 == "empty", v1[v1 != "empty"][1L]), by = v2]
```

Comment: thanks, but it might occur that the value is not unique in `v2`

Comment: So how would you want to assign it then? Maybe you should make you example more reproducible then.

Comment: by the first value occurence of a suitable value would be fine.

Comment: So my answer should still work, no? Can you check on your real data set?

Comment: I tried it, thanks. I see that NAs are introduced when there is no suitable mapping, is that working as intended?

Comment: Yes, what should it give instead of `NA`s?

Comment: it should leave the "empty"s as they are. But I can adjust this by hand.

Comment: another question, my data frame contains more than these two columns. Does this solution only apply to the columns `v1` and `v2` ?

Comment: Yes, it modifies only column `v1`.

Comment: still I am confused: here is (part of) my summary(df$v1) from before the solution:  EMPTY = 8476, HORMON= 9011, CHEMO = 32. But afterwards its: EMPTY= 3042, HORMON= 12509, CHEMO = 2.  Why did the CHEMOs become less? It should not even look at anything other than EMPTY

Comment: with @akrun solution I get: EMPTY=0, HORMON=9011, CHEMO=32, NA's=1. But that looks suspicious to me as I'm pretty sure there are more than 1 with no appropriate mapping.

Comment: Ok, does this works `df[!J("empty"), v1 := replace(v1, v1 == "empty", v1[v1 != "empty"][1L]), by = v2]` (though it similar to akruns solution)

Comment: this solution seems to be better:  EMPTY= 1674, HORMON= 14095, CHEMO= 32.

Comment: How do it scale though?

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, I'm buying it ;)

Answer (score 4):

One option is changing the 'empty' strings to 'NA' and then use `na.locf` to replace the `NA' values with the non-NA previous value.

```
 library(zoo)
 is.na(df) <- df=='empty'
 df[] <- lapply(df, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Or as @DavidArenburg suggested, if there are only 'character' columns, you can apply `na.locf` directly on the dataset, otherwise, may need to subset the dataset.  If the initial columns are 'factor' class, this would convert to 'character' even though the output is a 'data.frame'

```
 df[] <- na.locf(df, na.rm=FALSE)
```

If you want to return as 'empty' (it is better to keep as 'NA' values)

```
 df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {x1 <- na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE)
              replace(x1, which(is.na(x1)), 'empty') })
```

Comment: Probably just `na.locf(df, na.rm=FALSE)` is enough (not sure why you using `lapply`)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I haven't tested with mixed column class.

Comment: @DavidArenburg the `na.locf` returns a matrix and the class gets changed.  For example `df1 <- cbind(df, v3=c(1:5))` But, the character columns can be subsetted and do the `na.locf` directly on it

Comment: thanks for your solution, but can you please make this a bit more explicit. My real data frame contains more than these two rows and the comparison should only be made by these two columns, `v1` and `v2` in my example.

Comment: @spore234 If your want for only columns v1 and v2, subset the dataset for the two columns   `df[c('v1', 'v2')] <- lapply(df[c('v1', 'v2')], ...`